# Divi show/hide module through Custom Field GLOBALLY

Tags: wordpress, global, advanced-custom-fields, custom-fields, divi

I know this may sound familiar, however, I can't get it to work.
So with (or without) ACF you can create a Custom Field and use that in DIVI to show/hide a module.
However, from what I can see, this Custom Field may exist on EVERY PAGE, but the value can be different on every page.
What I'm looking for is a Custom Field that will have a setting (like text: "Yes"/"No", real simple) that will be 1 setting for the whole website. So set this somewhere to "Yes" and on ALL pages where the module has been integrated, the module will appear. Set the Custom Field to "No" and on ALL the pages the module will NOT appear.

I've tried creating a global variable instead (instructions for that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715465/how-do-i-create-a-universal-custom-field-in-wordpress)), but the global variable that's created there is NOT available as a "Custom Field"..

So how do I fix this?